# ApiPlatform Schema naming with sort of hash

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, api-platform.com

I know this may be a silly question but i cannot find out how to change (get rid of) the code after my resource name in schemas section generated with OpenApi (Swagger) of the ApiPlatform.

Definitoins are loaded by the phpdoc of my DTO `ClienteDtoOutput`, but where/how can i change the `Clienti:58c4a823efd9bfeab158f60692e79e88` name?

[image]